# How to access private members of an abstract class from its friend class?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, friend-class

```
class A  
{  
private:  
        int a,b,c;  
public:
        virtual int get()=0;
         friend class B;
};

class B{
//here I want to access private variables of class A that is a, b and c
};

class C:public class A
{  
        int get(){    
       //some code  
        }  
};
```

How to access private members of class A in class B. I cannot create an object of class A since it is abstract. I somehow have to use an object of class C to do that but how?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I am stuck. If I create an object of class C inside class B then it cannot access the private members of class A.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Show the real code with errors

Comment: @PuRaK _' If I create an object of class C inside class B ...'_ So why are you wondering about this? Only `B` was declared as `friend`, not `C`.

Comment: "then it cannot access the private members". This is not a problem report. "I get an error 'CXX1234: not enough gibz to make a fupz' on line 5678". This *is* a problem report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A {
    friend class B;
private:
    int x;
public:
    A() : x(42) {}
};

class C : public A {
};

class B {
public:
    int reveal_secrets(C &instance){
        // access private member
        return instance.x;
    }

    int reveal_secrets(){
        // access private member of instance created inside B
        C instance;
        return instance.x;
    }
};

void print_secrets(){
    C instance;
    B accessor;
    std::cout << accessor.reveal_secrets(instance) << ", " << accessor.reveal_secrets() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Incidentally never use virtual without making a virtual destructor.  That is item 7 in Scott Meyers' book "Effective C++" which I found very helpful early on.

Comment: I meant to type some commentary.  If you make A abstract, it changes nothing in this code.  Since A is abstract, you must create C (which is A).  Then B can access the A part of C.

Answer (score 1):

`class B` will *have* to have an instance object to work with in the first place.  **That** instance object is what `B` will look at in order to access `a`, `b`, *etc* .

Comment: `class B` does have an instance object to work with, of type `C`.

Comment: But the problem is that instance object cannot access the private members of class A. I have to somehow access them in class B. Is there any possible way of doing that in this situation?

Comment: @PuRaK if that object of type `C` is called `obj`, in `B` simply use `obj.a`, `obj.b`, *etc*

Comment: @PuRaK No, the problem is you not telling what errors you are getting. [Because you should not be getting any](http://ideone.com/6FvtvM).